Using VeraCrypt with few Windows installations on one SSD
I have 2TB SSD with installed Windows 11. Due to specific reasons, I need to install few more Windows 11 versions. I can do it by shrinking drive to partitions and install windows to each. The main problem that I need to encrypt entire drive or each partition (doesn't matter) with VeraCrypt.
Is it doable overall?
If yes, should I encrypt entire disk first and start to shrink after? Or I need to do all that steps before any kind of encryption?
Thank you!

It would seem far simpler to have a single OS on the disk, and use virtual machines for other versions. There are a number of VM's, such as free VirtualBox, that should make the job easy, and lessen risk of multiple entries into BitLocker, which seems to be asking for issues.
